# What are the connected components of $\Bbb R^2 \setminus \big(\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2, x^2+y^2=1\} \cup \{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2, y=x^2+1\}\big)$?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

What are the connected components of $\Bbb R^2 \setminus  \big(\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2,  x^2+y^2=1\} \cup \{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2, y=x^2+1\}\big)$ ?

I made a drawing and to me the connected components are:

- $\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2, y>x^2+1\}$
- $\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2,y^2+x^2 < 1\}$

Are there any others? How to prove it formally?

Comment: There should be one more. All you have to verify is that these are indeed connected and their disjoint union gives the whole space we started off.

Comment: Are you able to post a picture of your drawing (or a link to something like W|A showing the graph)? (I'm asking not for my benefit, but for your benefit, so we can point you in the right direction.)

Comment: Every open ball $B(p,r) = \{q \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid d(p,q) < r\}$ is connected. Your set contains infinitely many open balls, so it has infinitely many connected subspaces.

Comment: @LeeMosher: Though not specified, I'm leaning toward the student being interested in the connected components of such a space.

Comment: @Clayton That seems quite possible. But if so then the question, as it stands, shows some misunderstanding. Perhaps an awareness of the great abundance of connected subsets might lead to better understanding.

Comment: I think that the OP  is looking for the **connected components** and not the **connected subsets**. If that’s the case, see my answer below.

Comment: Sorry, I mis-translated to English, the right word is "component" indeed. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @astudentofmaths Are you a French maths student? Tricky to use the proper English math wording!

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net French yes, studying Maths at home, for myself by myself. Wording is important indeed, I will pay more attention to it in the future.

Comment: Where strange to close the question. The initial wording was unclear. But not the one of the last version. Can the one voting to close enlight us on the why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you were meaning to find the [connected components](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space), and not the connected subsets of $S=\Bbb R^2 \setminus \big(\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2, x^2+y^2=1\} \cup \{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2, y=x^2+1\}\big)$.

**Connected components** are the **maximal** (for set inclusion order) connected subsets.

If that was indeed your real question, then the connected components of $S$ are $S_1 =\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2, x^2+y^2  <1\}$ the open unit disk, $S_2=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2, y>x^2+1\}$ and $S_3=\mathbb R^2 \setminus \big(\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2, x^2+y^2 \le 1\} \cup \{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2, y \ge x^2+1\}\big)$.

You can verify that those sets are maximal connected subsets of $S$, disjoint and that their union is $S$.